# Bloques de Try and Catch

Tags: java, try-catch, menu

tengo una duda sobre los bloques de try and catch en java

mi codigo es el siguiente

```
 System.out.println("Bienvenido a la recopiladora de informacion");
    System.out.println("Por favor ingrese desde que estacionamiento se esta recopilando informacion");
    
    System.out.println("1.Estacionamiento zona 10");
    System.out.println("2.Estacionamiento zona 9");

    int estacionamiento = scanner.nextInt();

    try
    {
        switch(estacionamiento)
        {
            case 1:
            System.out.println("Hila");
            break;

            case 2:
            System.out.println("Hila 2");
            break;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("No ha ingresado un dato valido\n por favor ingrese un numero entero entre 1 y 2 para navegar por el programa");
    }
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que si el usuario agrega un valor diferente de 1 o 2, ya sea 0 o un dato que no sea entero que le arroje el mensaje de que esta agregando algo incorrecto, pero no se que poner en el parametro de catch. Que tipo de error sera mejor agregar o como manejarlo, me podrian ayudar?

Comment: El try-catch sirve para manejar excepciones en tiempo de ejecución (excepciones que no puedes prevenir lógicamente). El error en caso de que ingrese un valor que no sea numérico sería atrapado por el try, pero **para ello debe de estar DENTRO del try. dentro del catch va el manejo de la excepción**. Para el caso en que sea distinto, debes de hacer uso del **default**. Que es similar a un else en una secuencia `if-else if-else`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que haría es cambiar la variable `estacionamiento` a String, y parsear a Integer de esta forma sabría si no se puede parsear y me arroja error entonces el valor ingresado no es un número, en todo caso el valor ingresado sería un número; si quiero que pida el valor ingresado hasta que ingrese 1 o 2 tendría que estar dentro de un bucle.
Te dejo el programa comentado

```
public class TryCatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        //Este mensaje sólo se muestra una vez en el programa
        System.out.println("Bienvenido a la recopiladora de informacion"); 
        
        String estacionamiento; //Para almacenar lo que se ingresa por teclado
        int convertir = 0; //para convertir String a entero
        
        do{
                System.out.println("Por favor ingrese desde que estacionamiento se esta recopilando informacion");
                System.out.println("1.Estacionamiento zona 10");
                System.out.println("2.Estacionamiento zona 9");
                    
                estacionamiento = scanner.nextLine();
                
                if(isNumeric(estacionamiento)){// verificamos si es un número
                    convertir=Integer.parseInt(estacionamiento);
                    switch(convertir)
                    {
                        case 1:
                        System.out.println("Hola 1");
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        System.out.println("Hola 2");
                        break;
                        
                        default: //Si no ingresa número 1 o 2
                        System.out.println("Ingrese número 1 o 2 \n");
                    }
                }
                
                else //en caso si el valor ingresado no es un número
                      System.out.println("No ingresar letras \n");
                
        }while(convertir<1||convertir>2);        
    }
    
    private static boolean isNumeric(String cadena){
       try {
           Integer.parseInt(cadena);
           return true;
       } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
           return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un default, dentro del switch.

```
default:
System.out.println("Texto a mostrar");
```

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si ingresa una letra?